# How to aggregate an array of JSON Objects in Django with Postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql, psql

In Django 4.0+, I have an array of JSON objects that look like this:

```
[{'type': 'ORG', 'data':  "USA", "mentions": 8}, {'type': 'ORG', 'data':  "CA", "mentions": 15}, {'type': 'PERSON', 'data':  "Mahmoud", "mentions": 12}]
```

So, in each row, I will have similar data like that in an object field called `entities`.

What I am trying to achieve is to aggregate based on type with data and the total count of mentions of the same type and data and type in ALL rows.

In my queryset, I have tried the following code to get the total mentions aggergate (unsuccessfully):

```py
def get_named_entities(self):
        named_entities = self.exclude(entities__exact={}).exclude(entities__isnull=True).values('entities__type', 'entities__data', 'entities').annotate(
            mentions=RawSQL("CAST(JSONB_AGG(entities->>'mentions') AS INTEGER)", ())
        ).order_by('-mentions')
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work at all.